# Is there any "load policy" for new models in the same way as there are for new versions in Tensorflow-Serving?

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving

I have read on the official website that we can set a version policy preserving resources or disponibility for new versions but i haven't found anything about load new models. I'm using tensoflow-serving with Docker and I want to know what is the behavior for example if my allocated memory is full and I try to load a new one.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can load new versions of the same model by simply adding a new version to the folder, and you can load new models with a little bit of extra work.

**Add new version of a model**

To load new versions of the same model you would need to have a folder hierarchy and add the new version to the model folder with incrementing numbers. Imagine that you have this folder structure;

```
C:/mymodelfolder/
    L->resnet-model
      L->1
    L->nlp-model
      L->1
```

if you wish to load v2 of nlp-model, all you need to do is put the v2 of the model in a folder called `2` like so

```
C:/mymodelfolder/
   ...
    L->nlp-model
      L->1
      L->2  //new model is here
```

in a second or so, tf-serving should discover and load that model (you can discard the one of the models later on or serve them both with right configuration in an A/B manner)

**Add new model to be served**

in case you wish to load another model without restarting the tf-serving, you first would need to copy the model to another folder and then send a gRPC request to the exposed port of the app using a `ReloadConfigRequest` proto with all the models to be served. this way you can add/remove/specify versions dynamically.

there is also a flag => `--model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds` which tells tf-serving to listen to changes on the model.config file but I couldnt get that to work in the latest version on docker.

For official docs and more you may visit https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#model_server_config_details

**Memory Behavior**

> I want to know what is the behavior for example if my allocated memory
>   is full and I try to load a new one.

when you are updating a model to a new version, unless you configure them to be served together, the previous model gets unloaded and the new model gets loaded.  so if the first model has a different size than the second model, it will be reflected to the memory.

If you happen to load a model which would exceed the memory of the allocation for the app/container/environment then unfortunately in the current version of the app, it will shut itself down. but there is a lengthy conversation and some workarounds on this post which you may want to check out: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1215